# How to remove localstorage value in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-storage

I am using `[ngStorage][1]` module of AngularJS. Below is my code:

```
$localStorage.$reset();
```

it is removing all variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$localStorage.$reset({
    counter: 42
});
```

where `counter` is the key of your localStorage.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Ravi
I have tried this and it's work 
$localStorage.$reset({ RegField: undefined });